# django channels won't disconnect

Tags: django, django-channels

I'm using channels to long-poll a database so I'm using the `AsyncConsumer`. I can't get the disconnect method to run when the webpage closes or is manually refreshed.  I've tried creating;

- `def disconnect(self, close_code)`
- `def ws_disconnect(self, close_code)`
- `def websocket_disconnect(self, close_code)`

I've tried them with and without async in front.  I've also tried replacing the parameters with `'event'`.
When I first wrote the methods I included `channels.exceptions.StopConsumer()` but when that didn't work I placed a print statement inside my disconnect method just for testing and it appears that the disconnect method is never firing.

Apologies if this is a stupid question but I've spent 3 days trying everything that I could find on the internet.  When I close or refresh the page the terminal shows

> 'WebSocket DISCONNECT /page_name/ [127.0.0.1:35748]

and then a few seconds later there's a message which states

```
 'Application instance <Task pending coro=<__call__() running at /home/ecl/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/sessions.py:179> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task._wakeup()]>> for connection <WebSocketProtocol client=['127.0.0.1', 35746] path=b'/alertstatus/'> took too long to shut down and was killed.'
```

If anyone can give me any suggestions as to where to look for a solution to this I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

You should raise StopConsumer().

My example:

```py
from channels.exceptions import StopConsumer

...

async def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
    # Leave room group
    await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
        self.room_name,
        self.channel_name
    )
    raise StopConsumer()
```

it's work for me.

Comment: Most likely you don't need to override `websocket_disconnect` at all - the built-in version includes `raise StopConsumer()`. Stick with overriding `disconnect`.