# django channels error message on websocket start (Sessions.py)

Tags: django, websocket, real-time, django-channels

Whenever I start my django channels websocket. I get this:

```
2019-01-10 00:24:09,463 - WARNING - server - Application instance <Task pending coro=<SessionMiddlewareInstance.__call__() running at C:\Users\JAYK~1\Envs\jyst\lib\site-packages\channels\sessions.py:175> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x000001B067F32E58>()]>> for connection <WebSocketProtocol client=['127.0.0.1', 57367] path=b'/jysts/m/KIDA_TG'> took too long to shut down and was killed.
```

Comment: post your consumer and routing code

Comment: I got it fixed with adding StopConsumer() thank you.

Comment: Where did you add ```StopConsumer()``` ?? I have the same issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53445286/django-channels-wont-disconnect Please refer to this. You should be raising it on disconnect

Answer (score 1):

My application was raising the same Warning as stated in the question. After some time it would kill the asgi application and the Websocket could no longer be connected to until i restarted the service manually.

For me it was adding `raise StopConsumer()` to the disconnect function:

```py
def disconnect(self, close_code):
 # Leave room group
    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
        self.room_group_name,
        self.channel_name
    )
    raise StopConsumer()
```

> As stated by the [Channel Documentation](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/consumers.html):
> *"you need to raise channels.exceptions.StopConsumer to halt the ASGI application cleanly and let the server clean it up. If you leave it running - by not raising this exception - the server will reach its application close timeout (which is 10 seconds by default in Daphne) and then kill your application and raise a warning."*